# Q promises - Parse result vs nbind

Tags: node.js, promise, q

Im working with node.js, Mongoose and the Q library for promises (https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference)

I was wondering what's the difference between:

```
var Kitty = mongoose.model("Kitty");
var findKitties = Q.nbind(Kitty.find, Kitty);

findKitties({ cute: true }).done(function(theKitties) {
    console.log(theKitties);
});
```

and this:

```
var Kitty = mongoose.model("Kitty");
var query = Kitty.find({ cute: true });
Q(query.exec()).done(function(theKitties) {
    console.log(theKitties);
});
```

They both work, but which one is better? Are they the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Mongoose documentation for `exec()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate-exec) and you will see:

```js
aggregate.exec(callback);

// Because a promise is returned, the `callback` is optional.
var promise = aggregate.exec();
promise.then(..);
```

In other words, Mongoose's `exec` can follow node callback style *or* use promises.

The first example you provided, `Q.nbind()` assumes that `exec` uses node callbacks. In your second example `Q()` assumes that whatever passed into it is either a promise or a value.

The only reason both methods work is because Mongoose has implemented both node callbacks, and promises. This usually isn't the case!

---

Because Mongoose already supports promises natively, go for

```js
var query = Kitty.find({ cute: true });
Q(query.exec()).done(/* ... */);
```

instead of wrapping the node style callbacks:

```js
var findKitty = Q.nbind(Kitty.find, Kitty);
findKitty({ cute: true }).done(/* ... */);
```

---

To answer a question in the comments:

> do you have any information on update and delete?

take a look at the [queries documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html):

> When a callback function:
>
> - is passed, the operation will be executed immediately with the results
>     passed to the callback.
> - is not passed, an instance of Query is
>     returned, which provides a special QueryBuilder interface for you.

So basically it's possible to do something like this:

```js
var query = Kitty.update({ cute: false }); // :(
query.exec().then(/*  */)
```

instead of using nbind:

```js
var updateKitty = Q.nbind(Kitty.update, Kitty);
updateKitty({ cute: false }).then(/*  */)
```

Both will work, it's up to you if you want to execute the update at that moment by using a callback, or in another line using `exec`. Read that documentation for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. Just for the record, do you have any information on update and delete? I think they do need to use nbind right?

Comment: Glad to help. I've updated my answer - I've never used Mongoose so I've had to do some looking around.

Comment: Updated the first example. Basically build a query be it `Kitty.find` or `Kitty.update` and then call `.exec` to run that query and get back a promise.